# Blackberry MDS Simulator not launching

Tags: blackberry, java-me, mds-cs

I have a problem with MDS-CS simulator coming with JDE 4.5.0 installation.
I have to establish network connectivity and I need to run MDS for that.
Whenever I launch MDS simulator, a window appears and exits immediately.

How do I resolve this problem ?

I searched on internet for this issue and most answers were related to path environment variables.I have checked for correct path variables, but still not working.
I re-installed JDE, still no solution.

My Java home is under `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_12`

will this matter ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are running Vista, make sure that the Research in Motion directory has correct read/write/execute permissions. It's always the case when we install a new JDE or a new simulator in Vista, that this occurs; where half the things load, such as the JDE, and other things don't, such as the MDS and ESS, and the problem is, more often than not, that the directory settings are not appropriate. We typically just nuke that entire directory by changing the owner of the Research in Motion dir and subdirs to current user and setting everything in there to allow read/write/execute for current user. RIM installations simply don't play nice with the new Vista user access thing.

Aside from that, we have had occurrences where Java 1.6 simply did not work with MDS and ESS (especially the older 4.1.2 installation of the MDS/ESS package. If the permissions thing above doesn't work, try changing the active Java installation (the path to java.exe, essentially) to some version of Java 1.5.

Also, just re-reading your question, you should have a PATH variable in system variables pointing to the **bin** directory of your java JRE and java JDK installation -- that's where the executables live, and the MDS simply calls java.exe with its parameters, so the path needs to be set properly (and permissions on that dir need to be appropriate).

Comment: +1, apropriate KB article: http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800792/801079/Support_-_BlackBerry_Mobile_Data_Service_Simulator_does_not_launch.html?nodeid=800979&vernum=0

Comment: thanks - had the same problem b/c I was using 1.6...once I switched to 1.5 it worked

Answer (score 2):

You could also change the MDS install folder to somewhere outside the "Program Files". So you don't need to change the "read/write/execute" settings.